# Display not detected for Simulink Model Comparison

Tags: git, matlab, github, simulink, ubuntu-22.04

I'm working with Simulink (MATLAB2023a) and was looking for something for versioning that could report model changes in more or less detail. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNX7f0kPSYg) from Mathworks that links to [this repository](https://github.com/mathworks/Simulink-Model-Comparison-for-GitHub-Pull-Requests/tree/main) which seems to do the job for me by also generating comparison images of the model before and after.

I then followed the tutorial regarding the github-hosted virtual machine, so I looked at the file [githubrunner_push.yml](https://github.com/mathworks/Simulink-Model-Comparison-for-GitHub-Pull-Requests/blob/main/githubrunner_push.yml) and [diffGitHub_push.m](https://github.com/mathworks/Simulink-Model-Comparison-for-GitHub-Pull-Requests/blob/main/diffGitHub_push.m).

The problem is that although the report is generated with all the information about the changes, it results in this error:

> No display detected. Unable to create model screenshots.

whereas in the .yml file the display seems to be started correctly.

```
- name: Start Display Server
    run: |
     sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
     Xvfb :99 &
     export DISPLAY=:99
     echo "DISPLAY=:99" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

How could I solve this? Thanks

[image: Report error]

Comment: Doesn't sound like a git problem.

Comment: The latest version of ubuntu is used by default, I have also tried setting up earlier versions but the result has not changed.